# Java 11 upgrade missing javax.annotation.security

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat, gradle

Got a spring boot app I am upgrading to java 11. The war files is deployed in latest tomcat 9 which was started with open-jdk-11.

The code is still compiled in Java 8. First make it all runnable on Java 11 then start with module hazzle...

So I added `compile 'javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.3.2'` as dependecy but starting in tomcat yields (starting the runnable jar gives the same):

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet (in unnamed module @0x51d8cbdd) cannot access class javax.annotation.security.DeclareRoles (in module java.annotation) because module java.annotation does not export javax.annotation.security to unnamed module @0x51d8cbdd
at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadClassAnnotation(WebAnnotationSet.java:258) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar!/:8.5.34]
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationListenerAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:88) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar!/:8.5.34]
at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:67) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar!/:8.5.34]
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat$FixContextListener.lifecycleEvent(Tomcat.java:973) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar!/:8.5.34]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:94) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar!/:8.5.34]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5154) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar!/:8.5.34]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar!/:8.5.34]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1420) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar!/:8.5.34]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1410) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar!/:8.5.34]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[?:?]
```

Comment: There is no, officially, supported Spring Boot version that supports Java11.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What version of Spring Boot are you running? Java 11 support starts with 2.1 https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.1-Release-Notes

> Java 11 Support
>
> Spring Boot 2.1 remains compatible with Java 8 but now also supports Java 11. We  have continuous integration configured to build and test Spring Boot against the latest Java 11 release.